# How to mount skateboard wheels to an t-slotted framing

Tags: bearings, wheels

What is the best way to attach skateboard wheels to an t-slotted framing?
Also, is there a more economical way?

Bonus: How to design shock absorber for it?

Comment: make a bracket. design a bracket with hinge to add a shock absorber - such as a rubber pad.

Comment: Most economical will be an M8 bolt with its head ground down to fit in the slot, washer(s) to space the week from the extrusion, and a Nylock nut to keep the wheel from falling off.

Answer (score 0):

They have usually 7 inches wide trucks with 50mm diameter wheels pre-assembled with the shock absorber with 4-6 bolts going through the slotted opening. I show an example photo of Magnoto brand, I don't know them.

[image: side view]

[image: top view]

[image: bottom]
[image: truck]